# How to remove some article in text file that have amount of odd lines with PHP?

Tags: php, regex

I have hundreds of articles in one text file. Separation between the article

`I use tags <-----> and <*****>`.

**Example:**

```
<----->
sentence 1.1
sentence 1.2
<*****>
<----->
sentence 2.1
sentence 2.2
sentence 2.3
<*****>
<----->
sentence 3.1
sentence 3.2
<*****>

And now I want to remove articles that have odd number of sentences using PHP. Example:

<----->
sentence 1.1
sentence 1.2
<*****>
<----->
sentence 3.1
sentence 3.2
<*****>
```

Please help me, how to remove articles that have odd number of sentences using PHP?? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$string = ' 
<-----> <br>
sentence 1.1 <br>
sentence 1.2 <br>
<*****><br>
<-----><br>
sentence 2.1<br>
sentence 2.2<br>
sentence 2.3<br>
<*****><br>
<-----><br>
sentence 3.1<br>
sentence 3.2<br>
<*****><br>
';

$fullArticles = explode('<*****><br>', $string);
$output = ''; 
foreach ($fullArticles as $article) {
    $sentences = explode(PHP_EOL, $article);
    #remove empty lines, just in case
    $sentences = array_filter($sentences);
    #remove <----> separator, always first line of article
    array_shift($sentences);
    if (!empty($sentences) && count($sentences) % 2 == 0) {
        $output .= '<-----><br>' 
            . PHP_EOL 
            . join(PHP_EOL, $sentences) 
            . PHP_EOL 
            . '<*****><br>' 
            . PHP_EOL;
    }   
}

echo $output;
```

Read the whole input string into array of articles and then separate each article into array of sentences. Now you can easily check if the number of sentences is even or odd. When odd (I also added a condition for empty), then do not add it to output.
Reading from and saving to file is up to you. You may also want to create variables for your separators to not repeat yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Well this isnt a good way to handle a bunch of data, but anyway what I would offer is get all of the rows in the txt file into an arranged array, it would make it easier for to locate the current row you want to remove.

I would also recommand to add ID (uniqe) for every row in the txt file, that could also help you out handling a specific row.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php
(I guess you already got the txt file into one giant string, then this function can help you)